# VHDL Value in case statement randomly gets stuck at a certain value

Tags: button, case, vhdl

I've recently been working on some code trying to make a vending machine in vhdl. Started getting some strange errors and managed to narrow it down to my display value being updated.
The code is basically suppose to be able to toggle between display formats for a 7-segment display. I'd say it works as it should mostly but seemed to freeze randomly
I altered to code,found below, a little for debugging and noticed that the values within the case statement get stuck at a certain value. The rest of the code continuous to run perfectly so I can reset and it will work again. Below is the code with the problem

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity display_switch is
Port (  clk : in STD_LOGIC;
    reset: in STD_LOGIC;
    number : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (13 downto 0);-- unsigned binary number
    hexid   : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); -- hex representation
    sel : in std_logic;             
    an : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);      
    seg : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);   -- 7 segment display
    dp,Led,Led1,Led2 : out std_logic);
  end display_switch;

  architecture bhv of display_switch is


type button_state is(dec,hex,deb);  -- states for display formats                                                   
signal current_display,next_display : button_state; 


process(clk, reset)
begin

if reset = '1' then     -- asynchronous reset
current_display <= dec;
next_display <= hex;
decp <= '1';            -- decimal point


elsif rising_edge(clk) then
  segm_display <= hexid;

 case current_display is
when dec =>     Led2 <= '1';
            Led1 <= '0';
            Led <= '0';
            decp <= '0';

            next_display <= hex;
        if sel = '1' then
        current_display <= deb;
        end if;
when hex => Led2 <= '0';
        Led1 <= '1';
        Led <= '0';
        decp <= '1';

        next_display <= dec;
        if sel = '1' then
        current_display <= deb;
        end if;
when deb => Led2 <= '0';
        Led1 <= '0';
        Led <= '1';

        if sel /= '1' then
        current_display <= next_display;
        end if;
when others => current_display <= dec;
end case;   
 end if;
 end process;
 end bhv;
```

Basically what happens is that the output values in the case statements either all get stuck at '1' or all get stuck at '0'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your computation for the next states is dubious. If you are using a synchronous process (as you are indeed doing), you do not need a `next_display` signal. Just assign the next state value to `current_display` instead.

Comment: I would still need some if clause to know what my previous display was so I know which to go to next.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was a timing issue with the "sel" input variabel.

added a signal to store the value  on rising clock edge.

```
temp <= sel;
```

then used that temp variable instead.

Comment: Your example code is hardly an example of clarity and doesn't lead to someone helping you finding the solution.  Assignment to sel is external to the code example, the process statement and it's if statement are missing end statements as is the architecture body, there are two missing declarations (decp, and segm_display), the architecture body is missing a begin statement. Also your choices for the current_display case statement already cover all values of button_state.  The others choice is superfluous.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I left out some of the code since this was the only part that was acting funny.

Comment: The last superfluous case was added cause I thought that was causing the error. I missed the end statements here out of haste. In any case I managed to find the problem, thanks anyhow